# Function logic works after random number of attempts

Tags: php, symfony

I cannot figure out why my `removeAction` function works after a random number of attempts. Sometimes it work’s the first time and others I have to click over and over again (4 or 5 times) until it works.

I know it works because the product id is removed from the users cart.

I’m not sure if this helps but I checked the max_execution_time (which is `30`) against the `microtime()` of the function (which is `float(0.0148420333862)`).

And when I dump `$quantity` and `$cart` I see the correct product id at all times.

`removeAction function`:

```
    /**
     * Removes a 'product' from the cart
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/remove", name="product_remove")
     * @METHOD("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function removeAction(Request $request, $id) {

       // $time = microtime(true);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $product = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->find($id);

        $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'submitted' => false]);

        $quantity = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Quantity')->findOneBy(['product' => $product->getId()]);
                                                //get product id from the cart and then remove it

    // product gets removed but only after a random # of click on the remove button...

//ini_get('max_execution_time');
//var_dump(ini_get('max_execution_time'));

        // dump($quantity);
        // dump($cart);


        $em->remove($quantity);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product: '.$product->getName().' was removed!');

        //var_dump(microtime(true) - $time); die;

        return $this->redirectToRoute('product_showCart');
    }
```

Comment: That looks like a weird way to do things. I can't see how that would work? Surely you have a relation from cart to the products in it? What if the same product is in multiple carts? How does that code know which cart to remove from? Your method doesn't make a lot of sense when I read it. I re-wrote how I would expect this to work in a standard fashion below.

Comment: It probably is a weird way of doing this haha. I'm new but I'm learning. I was able to get this working but fixing this: `$quantity = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Quantity')->findOneBy(['product' => $product->getId()]);` to this: `$quantity = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Quantity')->findOneBy(['product' => $product->getId(), 'userCart' => $cart->getId()]);`

Comment: That looks way better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where I make some assumptions about your code, but it's roughly how I'd expect things to work and a lot simpler.

You should be able to inspect Cart and find the matching item and remove it that way, if not then you should probably refactor how your cart is constructed.

I would guess that the reason your original code worked after a bunch of clicks is it removed the product from all the carts it was in until it got to your cart, which is not ideal obviously.

```
/**
 * Removes a 'product' from the cart
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/remove", name="product_remove")
 * @METHOD("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function removeAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'submitted' => false]);

    // Surely you must have some sort of cart->product or cart -> cartitem -> product relation here - I make some assumptions but what you
    // do should ideally work similar to this.

    foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) {

        if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $id) {

            $em->remove($item);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product was removed!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('product_showCart');
        }
    }

    // here you could put some kind of error because you failed to remove the product        
}
```

Comment: A few hours after I figured out my solution I did something similar to this in a different function in my controller! But thanks for your input